# PHP: How to find multiple strpos()

Tags: php

I have a string with the value in the format below

`10:00 AM, 31 January 2017`

The first task my client assigned me was to find January in that string which I have succeeded using the code below

```
<?php

$season_date = "10:00 AM, 31 January 2017";

if(strpos($season_date, 'January') !== false  ) {
 echo "True"; // Apply price increase percentage
}

?>
```

Now he has extended the task to find dates range for eg:

`20 January - 02 February`

How do I go about in doing this?

**Edited:**

I just realized my problem is bigger than the above. I actually have 2 dates

`$start->format('g:i A, d F Y');` and `$end->format('g:i A, d F Y');`

So it's not just the matter of finding the specified string within the `start` and `end` dates, but also `in between`. Argh.

**My final code. Thanks to everyone :)**

```
<?php

    $daterange_season = array('2017-01-20', '2017-02-15'); /* 20 January 2017 - 15 February 2017 : Season */    
    $daterange_booked = array($book_start_date, $book_end_date);

    $range_min = new DateTime(min($daterange_season));
    $range_max = new DateTime(max($daterange_season));

    $start_book = new DateTime(min($daterange_booked));
    $end_book = new DateTime(max($daterange_booked));

    if ($start_book >= $range_min && $end_book <= $range_max) {
      echo 'Yes. Within season. Charge me!';
    } else {
      echo 'My booking is not within Peak Season, dont charge me!';
    }

?>
```

Comment: @lwani Don't you have year in you second task to get range between two date ?

Comment: Yes @Tiger

I'm required to apply the price increase percentage between `20 January 2017` to `02 February 2017`.

Comment: Guys, thanks for your replies so far. Let me try something first and come back and pick the answer that helped me the most. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime).

**Task 1**

```
$season_date = strtotime("10:00 AM, 31 January 2017");
echo $month=date("F",$season_date);
```

**Task 2**

```
$begin = new DateTime("20 January 2017");
$end = new DateTime("02 February 2017");

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);
// $end = $end->modify( '+1 day' );  // Uncomment this line if you want to include end date in the range.

foreach($daterange as $date){
    echo $date->format("Y-m-d") . "<br>";
}
```

[More Details](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php)

Comment: Thanks @tiger. Let me try this out!

Comment: Your answer is very helpful to me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.preg-match.php).

```
[0-9]{1,2} January
```

matches any string of type 2 January, 02 January or 20 January.

Comment: @Federkun better?

Comment: Thanks @TigOldBitties I think I have a bigger problem. I just realized it. I have 2 dates, 

`$start->format('g:i A, d F Y');` and `$end->format('g:i A, d F Y');` it's not just the matter of finding the date within the `start` and `end` dates, but also `in between`. Argh.

Comment: Regex is incredibly versatile, can help you with strings. Since you already have dates why not work with dates directly? Your question was about strings for which you can always use regex, but in this case try working directly with dates.

Comment: Thanks @TigOldBitties let me try this out!